# Cannot understand COVERING INDEX query plan for UPDATE query

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a SQLite table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA (ColumnA INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                     ColumnB INTEGER NOT NULL,
                     ColumnC TEXT NOT NULL)
```

And I've created two indexes on this table as follows:

```
CREATE INDEX ColumnB_ColumnC_on_TableA ON TableA (ColumnB ASC, ColumnC ASC)
CREATE INDEX ColumnC_on_TableA ON TableA (ColumnC ASC)
```

When I run the EXPLAIN QUERY command on the following query...

```
UPDATE TableA SET ColumnB = 1 WHERE ColumnC = '1'
```

... I see output as follows...

```
SEARCH TABLE TableA USING COVERING INDEX ColumnC_on_TableA (ColumnC=?)
```

I can't understand why the query plan says that the `ColumnC_on_TableA` index is a covering index when the index does not cover all of the columns in the table. Can anyone make sense of this and explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [covering index](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html#covidx) is an index that covers all columns that are actually used *in the search*.

An UPDATE always reads/writes the entire table row (and the corresponding index entries), but for finding the rows to be updated, reading the contents of any table row is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the response CL but I still don't get it. In the example in my question, the EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN output says that `TableA` was searched using the covering index `ColumnC_on_TableA`. What confuses me is that `ColumnC_on_TableA` is not a covering index. (The other index is a covering index, i.e. `ColumnB_ColumnC_on_TableA`) Am I reading/understanding the output incorrectly?

Comment: Gotcha! That makes sense now. So by way of example: the query plan of `SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE ColumnC = '1'` is `SEARCH TABLE TableA USING INDEX ColumnC_on_TableA (ColumnC=?)` and the query plan of `SELECT ColumnC FROM TableA WHERE ColumnC = '1'` is `SEARCH TABLE TableA USING COVERING INDEX ColumnC_on_TableA (ColumnC=?)`.